# iOS load 2 web views depending on user first launch

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, webview

hi apologies for my spelling and English in advance

what I want is to build a Webview application for iOS in objc or swift doesn't matter, the app works with 2 url links in the Webview to do the following.

Q1. url1  opens only on app first launch 
then inside url 1 there will be a register info form where the user should insert he's information after this info Is completed the user then push button "continue" inside Webview to continue to the website home page inside the webiview.

Q2. if app closes and reopens again then the app should register or remember that url 1  was opened and the "continue" button inside the Webview, was pushed there for this app then needs to open url2  and always open this url. I have builded this application in android but cannot get this in iOS. please help  thank you in advance nd sorry for the way of this explanation im new in iOS and need to finish this app with in 3days. thanks for your attention.

Comment: if any one know about a example project or can give me of help me with code for this please help out...

Comment: Does your application do anything more than just use a webview and a website? Just in case you may not be aware, Apple will not approve applications that only use webviews pointing to websites. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421002/app-rejected-from-apple-app-store-because-uiwebview-need-some-advice

Comment: yes there are a couple of features in the app for example on button push send sms notification to server for the company to phone the client, push on button dialer opens and phones the company. there are also external links in the app witch will open new browser out side of the app for sales. activity indicator inside app also a couple of images to display thru app natively for example if internet connection off etc...

Comment: Ok cool. As long as there exists more than just a web view then you should  be fine. I would however encourage the use of a custom login view rather than just the web view. That way you can intercept the success or failure messages and Store whether the user is logged in and redirect as necessary by checking whether they're logged in.

Comment: I do agree with you but my superior at work does not want it this way and thats why I am on stack overflow to see if I can get any one that can help me to do it this way I asked.

Comment: Sounds like What you're really asking for is someone to build this for you given you're inexperience with iOS development? If so let me know and perhaps I can help a little further.

Comment: that is pretty much what I need, I did build this app in android and now they want it in iOS and the iOS developer at my work resigned so im alone and have no clue what I should do?

Comment: thanks a million will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to create a redirect url for your login api which will be opened if successful registered. Next set delegate of your webview. Use this delegate method to identify redirect url.

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

Then set bool in NSUserDefaults like

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"IsUserLoggedIn"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Synchronize is method to persist value immediately. NSUserDefaults is persistent way to store flags. It persist its value until app is not deleted from device. You can update its value any time or remove value for any key with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey: @"IsUserLoggedIn"];
```

Then on app launch get the value for key "IsUserLoggedIn" in bool and load url accordingly

```
BOOL isloggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"IsUserLoggedIn"];
```

**Note**: If you want to make your app live on App Store. Then if your app will contain only a view with webview. Then apple will not approve it. Instead you need to add some native functionality. For eg. About Us, Contact Us page and Social Sharing.

Comment: Where will @davie intercept the login credentials though given the interaction is with the webpage not the apps native inputs?

Comment: @davie can create a successful signup page and redirect to that page if success registered. Then in webview delegate we can check if that url is trying to load in webview that means registration is successful. So we can set our user default in webview delegate method.

Comment: I tried this method thanks for the help but I am really new in iOS there for I ont really understand what your talking about but let me send a post from my android app coding to show what I want in iOS code. maybe you could understand and see precisely what I want

Comment: one quick question before I upload the android coding is there not an example project on GitHub or anywhere to look at because I do understand what you are saying but can't get into place where everything should go to etc.

Comment: @davie have you do some code on iOS it will be really help if you show me your iOS code.

Comment: as I said to the other person im talking to I am an android developer but the iOS developer resigned and he did nothing on this app didn't even start this project yet now I need to finish this project by Monday. and here in RSA it is Friday afternoon so basically if I don't find. solution by Sunday im screwed lol so thats why im basically begging for help.

Comment: @davie i am sorry i didn't see your comment. So did my answer helped you. I think it is as you accept my answer and thanks for it buddy.